# I want to write an expression like this, but I've never seen it before.

Tags: equations, formatting

I want to write an expression almost the same as that in the picture, but I don't know which package should be used and what kind of grammar I should write down. Thank you all! 
[image]

Comment: looks like something for `lstlistings` or an algorithm package.

Comment: I prefer `lstlistings`. It doesn't look like algorithm. I'm not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing special, probably it was created by the `verbatim` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
expr ::
        atom                    ;; a variable identifier
        | "!" expr              ;; logical not
        | expr1 "&" expr2       ;; logical and
        | expr1 "|" expr2       ;; logical or
        | expr1 "->" expr2      ;; logical implication
        | expr1 "=" expr2       ;; logical equivalence
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]